# How to show/hide a Modal using React-Bootstrap and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

I'm learning redux and I'm trying to get it to work with a react-bootstrap modal. I want the modal to show when the state in redux is set to true. However, when I try to get the state from redux the modal never shows even though the state changes to true.

It works fine when using regular state components (useState, setState).

Is there a reason the following code doesn't work?

Example React Component:

```js
const Example = () => {
  const showStore = createStore(showStore.reducer)

  const handleShow = () => {
    showStore.dispatch({type: 'SHOW'})
  }
 
  const handleClose = () => {
    showStore.dispatch({type: 'HIDE'})
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleShow}>
        Show modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={showStore.getState()} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>

        <Modal.Body>
          <Form>
            <Form.Label>Insert text</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Sample text" />

            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button onClick={handleClose}>
                Cancel
              </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  
  )
}

export default Example
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

showStore:

```js
const reducer = (state = false, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW' :
      return true
    case 'HIDE' :
      return false
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default { reducer }
```

Comment: why are you creating your store inside of your component? obviously, this state is not useful to you and cause such problem as you described.

Answer (score 2):

With Redux the typical way would be to define the reducer and store in one file:

**store/index.js:**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const modalReducer = (state = false, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW':
      return true;
    case 'HIDE':
      return false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const showStore = createStore(modalReducer);

export default showStore;
```

Your `<Example>` component is essentially the same with some minor changes indicated by the comments in the snippet below:

**Example.js**

```
function Example() {
  // Removed as store creation is now done in the store file
  // const showStore = createStore(showStore.reducer)

  // Extract data from the Redux store state and assign to const
  const showModal = useSelector((state) => state);
  
  const handleShow = () => {
    showStore.dispatch({ type: 'SHOW' });
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    showStore.dispatch({ type: 'HIDE' });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleShow}>Show modal</Button>

      // Changed to use const declared above
      <Modal show={showModal} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>

        <Modal.Body>
          <Form>
            <Form.Label>Insert text</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Sample text" />

            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You then wrap the usage of your component with `<Provider>` (passing the store as a prop) so it becomes:

**App.js**

```
render(
  <Provider store={showStore}>
    <Example />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

making sure you import `showStore`:

```
import showStore from './store';
```

There's a working StackBlitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-react-bootstrap-in-react-app-yur5vo?file=index.js).